# How to use sed in a sequence

Tags: sed

It seems like sed runs the following script in parallel but i want it to do it sequentially.

```
printf '%s\n' aa bb cc dd | sed 's/bb/\nff/g;/^$/d'
```

This sed script replaces bb with ff and adds a newline while also removing empty lines.

suppose i want if to add the newline and then remove the new line i just added.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` normally processes the file one line at a time, but if you add newlines (or use certain `sed` commands that read/add content to the "pattern space"), it can contain multiple lines at the same time. In particular when your `sed` script processes the line "`bb`", it first replaces it with "`\nff`" (where the `\n` represents an actual newline), then compares the entire pattern space with the regex `^$`, finds that it doesn't match, and ignores that command. (Note: in this context, `^` and `$` don't refer to the beginning and end of the line, the refer to the beginning and end of the pattern space).

Solution: if I understand your goal correctly, the second test should check for the pattern space starting with a newline (`^\n`) and if so delete the newline (*not* the entire pattern space). You can do this with the substitution `s/^\n//`.

Essentially, this will add a line break if the "bb" pattern was at the beginning of a line, but not if it's later in the line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' aa bb cc dd prefixbbsuffix | sed 's/bb/\nff/g;s/^\n//'
aa
ff
cc
dd
prefix
ffsuffix
```

Alternately, you could run two separate `sed` commands, so the second one re-breals lines treating the added line as a separate item:

```
printf '%s\n' aa bb cc dd prefixbbsuffix | sed 's/bb/\nff/g' | sed '/^$/d'
aa
ff
cc
dd
prefix
ffsuffix
```

If that's not your actual goal, please edit your question to clarify it.